# Extend a regular expression to negative number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to extend the following regex to negative numbers.

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
```

I tried adding minus sign doing something like this, (/[^-0-9.]/g, "") but this allows minus sign to be entered anywhere in the number. I want to allow only one occurance of the minus sign at the beginning of the number. Later occurances of minus should be ignored.

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uh, replacing every non-number character makes that a bit harder - it's like "negating" the regex. What I came up with is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), preventing a minus - which would be matched by `[^0-9.]` - from beeing matched if it is in the beginning of the string (using a [start anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)):

```
….replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9.]/g, "")
```

Comment: Most simply with removing all supernumerous dots in a second step. Updating the regex would get too complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Why RegEx? How about:

```
var temp = parseFloat(this.value)
this.value = isNaN(temp) ? "" : temp;
```

This should also work:

```
var temp = +this.value;
this.value = isNaN(temp) ? "" : temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your dash outside of the character class:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/^-?[^0-9\.]/g, "");
```

Comment: The OP wants to match (and remove) all characters that can not be part of a (possibly negative) number.

Answer (score 0):

The regex in provided by you is faulty for the positive numbers itself as it will convert "100+200=300" to "100200300".

I suggest you try this:
someString.match(/-?[\d]+.?[\d]*/);

Answer (score 0):

It is only to put the negative symbol in front of the 0

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^-0-9\.]/g, "");
```