# Allowing negative and positive decimals in javascript.replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this to filter out everything that isn't a number (including decimals)

On keydown I am doing this:

```
function validateNudgerInput(ele){
          ele.val(ele.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
            if (parseFloat(ele.val())> settings.max
              ||parseFloat(ele.val())< settings.min)
            {
              ele.addClass("nudgerInvalid ")
            }else{
             ele.removeClass("nudgerInvalid")
            }
        }
```

Currently Using: 
`ele.val(ele.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));`
This strips out anything that isnt a number above zero (decimals allowed) -i.e. If a user presses the "A" key, it will stop this from being placed in the textbox

How would I adapt this to allow negative numbers too? (Allowing the - sign)

Examples of valid input:
`1`
`-1` 
`123.45`
`-123.45`

Comment: Why decimals are not numbers?

Comment: Maybe allow minus signs as well?

Comment: @VisioN Sorry, I meant Negative and Positive decimals

Comment: Could you explain why you are doing this? What problem are you trying to solve? You could just add `-` to the character class, then the replacement process might yield something like `4-2` which you might not want. Some examples of inputs and desired outputs would be helpful.

Comment: Update your question making abstraction of jquery, it is only a regex problem. From what to what should be the replacement?

Comment: @FelixKling As I mentioned, I want to strip out any input in this particular field which isn't a number - be it positive or negative. (Including decimal numbers). For example somebody couldn't enter things like "123A" or "12.3!"

Comment: Why not use isNaN(parseFloat(ele.val())) ?

Comment: Ok, but what should the result for `"foo42-bar21"` be?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Extend a regular expression to negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845580/extend-a-regular-expression-to-negative-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will parse more numbers:

```
yourString.replace(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/g,'')
```

**EDIT** : To match one number from the begining to the end of the input:

```
yourString.match(/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/,'')
```

Comment: You need to use `.match` though, not `.replace`.

Comment: This does remove all numbers?

Comment: Thanks, this regex works providing i use "match". The downside is that It strips the textbox of the `-` symbol when I attempt to enter `-1` manually. This may just be a case of getting it to ignore that keycode.

Comment: `yourString.replace(/[^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?]/g,'')`

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper: No, that is just wrong. That is equivalent to `/[^-?\[\]0-9\(\).+]/g`, i.e. it will replace any character that is not `-`, `?`, `[`, `]`, `0-9`, `(`, `)`, `.` or `+`.

Comment: Yes, be careful where you put brackets, in this case `^` will have another meaning.

Comment: @FelixKling That's is what I wanted to do. Only allow those characters and not A-Z/Symbols

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper: But as I said, it also allows `+`, `[`, `]`, `?`, `(` and `)`. In any order. That's why I asked what the result for `"foo42-bar21"` should be. With your approach it will be `42-21`, which might be what you want, but that's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing this to restrict input on a text box.  What I would normally do is remember the value the last time you validated the text box, and if the current value is not valid, e.g. does not match the regex `/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/` for example, revert to the previous value.

Comment: A backslash is needed for the dot.

Comment: I actually have one (I copy/pasted direct from working code) but stackoverflow is not showing it.  Maybe it needs to be escaped?  I'll try to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testFloat(id)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    // allows only integer and float values (negative, positive)  
    obj.value = obj.value.replace(/([^-\d.]+)?((-{0,1}\d*\.?\d*)(.*)?$)/, "$3");            
}

HTML:<input type="text" id="testId"  onkeyup="testFloat(this.id)"/>
```

Hope this helps. :)